# Is there a way to tell how a program in Synaptic was originally installed?

Tags: software-sources, synaptic

I'm running RStudio. There's an update available, but the update isn't in Synaptic. Synaptic is aware of RStudio, however, and shows that it is installed.

I think I may have installed it initially by downloading the .deb, but I'm not sure. There's no indication in the properties for the package.

Is there another way to tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the "origin" button in the lower-left corner, and the list above will show the repositories for your packages. If the program you are looking for is under Local it was installed manually using a deb package.

For the RStudio desktop application case I'm pretty sure it has to be install/update by hand.